# jquery multidimensional array shuffle random

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to minimize my code from:

```
myArrayA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
fisherYates(myArrayA);
myArrayB = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
fisherYates(myArrayB);
myArrayC = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
fisherYates(myArrayC);
myArrayD = [16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
fisherYates(myArrayD);
myArrayE = [21, 22, 23, 24, 25];
fisherYates(myArrayE);
```

To:

```
var multArr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]];
fisherYates(multArr);
```

The output I want is like this:

```
[4,2,3,5,1],[7,10,6,9,8],[11,15,12,14,13],[18,17,16,20,19],[22,21,25,23,24]
```

I tried this code:
http://jsfiddle.net/arrow/yFn8U/

```
function fisherYates(myArray) {
var i = myArray.length, j, tempi, tempj;
if (i === 0) return false;
while (--i) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    tempi = myArray[i];
    tempj = myArray[j];
    myArray[i] = tempj;
    myArray[j] = tempi;
}
}
var multArr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]];
fisherYates(multArr);
```

But my code only randomizes the order of the chunks not the values in each chunk.
The output I want is like this:

```
[4,2,3,5,1],[7,10,6,9,8],[11,15,12,14,13],[18,17,16,20,19],[22,21,25,23,24]
```

I want each chunk inside the array to be in the same order but each chunk must be randomized.
Is there a way to do this with jQuery?
I also wonder how to get values from the shuffled/randomized array?
At the moment I get the values like this:

```
myArrayA[i]
myArrayB[i]
myArrayC[i]
myArrayD[i]
myArrayE[i]
```

I would guess I will get them with something like:

```
multArr [[0][i]];
multArr [[1][i]];
multArr [[2][i]];
multArr [[3][i]];
multArr [[4][i]];
```

Finally I wonder if minimizing the code will give better performance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you simply want to run an operation over all the elements in an array, then you should use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). I'm sure jquery provides shims for these methods in older browsers. So if we assume you're using your original `fisherYates` function unaltered, we might have something like this:

```
var multArr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]];
multArr.forEach(fisherYates);
```

On accessing the elements, you're almost right, but you have one set too many of brackets :

```
multArr[1]; // == [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
multArr[1][3]; // == 9
```

I wouldn't speculate about the performance, if you're really worried you should put together a jsperf test case.

Comment: Thanks a lot David! Exactly what I needed :) I dont have 15 reputation so I can't +1 this.

Comment: @user2395212 lol, or traditional forEach, same dif. welcome to SO!

Comment: David, I also want to mention that I now see more uses in my other code for forEach. Thanks again.

Comment: So I got 18 reputation now :) so I +1 your answer now David

Answer (score 3):

All you need is jQuery's .each() method, like so:

```
$.each(multArr, function(i) { fisherYates(this) });
```

See console on 

### this working example

### Fiddle Code

```
function fisherYates(myArray) {
    var i = myArray.length, j, tempi, tempj;
    if (i === 0) return false;
    while (--i) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        tempi = myArray[i];
        tempj = myArray[j];
        myArray[i] = tempj;
        myArray[j] = tempi;
    }
}
$(function() {
    $("button").on("click", function(e) {
        multArr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]];
        $.each(multArr, function(i) { fisherYates(this) });
        console.log(multArr)
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you. it works good. I looked at the code and I wonder where the i in 'function(i)' get it's value from? Or doesn't it need a value since the fisherYates function is containing (i === 0) ? I guess you are passing the i into the fisherYates function or am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry about the 'function(i)'-question. I think I understand the code now. the 'i' in 'function(i)' could be any other letter or word? Or am I wrong again?

Comment: @user2395212 Yes. The "i" simply means "index". U can make it any letter or word,  but it will still mean index

Comment: And in this case its not needed, just a force of habbit

Answer (score 3):

Check out my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fWZt7/1/). Basically just looped over the elements of the multidimensional array and run the fisherYates on them like so:

```
function fisherYates(myArray) {
    for(var i = 0; i< myArray.length; i++) {
       k = myArray[i].length;
       while(k--){
            j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (myArray.length - 1));
            tempk = myArray[i][k];
            tempj = myArray[i][j];
            myArray[i][k] = tempj;
            myArray[i][j] = tempk;
       }
    }
}
```

Now if you wanted to do this for an n-dimensional array you're going to have to do it recursively, which would be fun, but I think that is more than you were asking for. If not I can update it later.

Comment: Whoops, didn't get that warning to see other answers before posting. The foreach method is definitely the cleanest approach for what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you Scott101. That works like I wanted. I'm also interested in the n-dimensional array. do you have an example? I really don't know what an n-dimensional array is but seeing some code will probably make me understand. Thanks!

Comment: OK, then I will use the forEach approach. Thanks for the info.

Comment: A little late, but if you had an array of arrays of arrays of arrays... n times, then you would have an n dimensional array. So basically in the example above, you have a 3 dimensional array (a one dimensional array would be a single value, a two dimensional array is a standard array of values). Sof if you wanted to make it a four dimensional array each element in the inner arrays e.g.(1,2,3,..,25) would be an array themselves. But again, probably more than was necessary for your question.

Comment: Thank you Scott101. I think I begin to understand n-dimensional arrays now.